# use explode or any method to make break line in phpseclib output

Tags: php, ssh, explode, phpseclib

the output when I use phpseclib with simple command isn't like when I use putty or other ssh tools,

**in putty it's like**

line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

**in my browser it's look like**
line 1 line 2 line 3 line 4

when I **ctrl+u in my browser** to see the source, it's just like putty format
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

my mentor said that I can use method explode to make break line,

```
echo explode ("\n", $ssh->read());
```

but the output became
**Array to string conversion**

So, after read some link, I'm trying to use ANSI file in phpseclib to remove ANSI char, and the output format it's just like what I want.
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4

**but** the background color became black,

**QUESTION**
1. With ANSI file to remove ANSI char, can I change background color as default?
2. If with explode method can do what I mean, is there any example you guys may know?

I use local (xampp) server  and windows as my OS,

Comment: Put it in a `<pre>` tag: `echo '<pre>' . $ssh->read() . '</pre>';`

Comment: New lines are not rendered in html, which is why they don't show in the browser. Since the page is not being rendered in the view-source they will appear.

Comment: thanks for you guys responses
I'm using @jeroen suggested, it's works, thanks for your help :D